# How can I temporarily diable all local notifications when user disable it by using UISwitch?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, apple-push-notifications

I want to use UISwich in my setting page, if user turn it off, it will temporarily disable all local notifications.

In swift `application.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: nil))` to register local notifications.

Is there a function I can unregister local notifications, just like user turn the specific notification from the setting page in iOS??

Comment: You would need to somehow store the scheduled notifications before cancelling them all. If the user turns it back on just reschedule them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First Method**

1. When the user changes the value of the switch, you can store its status in NSUserDefaults.
2. When receiving a notification either through `application(_:didReceiveLocalNotification:)` or `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:` perform a check on the status change mentioned above, and if the user has turned off notifications, just ignore them.

**Second Method**

Use [unregisterForRemoteNotifications()](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/unregisterForRemoteNotifications)

> You should call this method in rare circumstances only, such as when a
> new version of the app removes support for all types of remote
> notifications. Users can temporarily prevent apps from receiving
> remote notifications through the Notifications section of the Settings
> app. Apps unregistered through this method can always re-register.

**Third Method**

When using *remote* notifications, you'll have server side code pushing these out to APNS. In cases like this, when a user wants to stop notifications, you can set a flag server side telling it to no longer send them to APNS.

Comment: `unregisterForRemoteNotifications` is irrelevant, OP's concerned with local notifications only.

Comment: Ok, I though there is a function like unregisterForRemoteNotifications() but for local notifications. It looks like there isn't one.

Comment: That is correct. I'm just being thorough should anyone else stumble across this question, and your title says ALL notifications. The first point in my answer should work well for you.

Comment: Thanks! BTW: How can I ignore notification in application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:? Just if true then return?

Comment: Yes, that's all you should have to do, except in your case you'll be using `didReceiveLocalNotification`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you import UIKit and UserNotifications
The following code is in swift 3

```
func removeLocalNotifications() {

    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getPendingNotificationRequests(completionHandler: {requests -> () in
            print("\(requests.count) requests -------")
            for request in requests{
                let notifIdentifier: String = request.identifier as String
                print("notifIdentifier deleted: \(notifIdentifier)")
                UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removePendingNotificationRequests(withIdentifiers: [notifIdentifier])
            }
        })
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getDeliveredNotifications(completionHandler: {deliveredNotifications -> () in
            print("\(deliveredNotifications.count) Delivered notifications-------")
            for notification in deliveredNotifications{
                let notifIdentifier: String = notification.request.identifier as String
                print("notifIdentifier deleted: \(notifIdentifier)")
                UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeDeliveredNotifications(withIdentifiers: [notifIdentifier])
            }
        })
    } else { ///for iOS < 10
        let app: UIApplication = UIApplication.shared
        for oneEvent in app.scheduledLocalNotifications! {
            print("oneEvent Deleted ======================= \(oneEvent)")
            let notification = oneEvent as UILocalNotification
            app.cancelLocalNotification(notification)
        }
    }
}
```